# Prevent gradient-background from continuing into the entire page whenever the element occurs

Tags: html, css

I have an element that repeats in a flex container. The element in turn has 3 elements. In order to to share the linear gradient, `background-attachment:fixed` is used but this causes the gradient to continue across elements.

These elements in turn have some absolute/relative positioning being applied. If this has to be repeated inside a flex container, the gradient is continuing, which is not desired.

```css
.wrapper1 {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  left: 80px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  left: -40px;
}

.wrapper3 {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  right: 90px;
}

.wrapper1,
.wrapper2,
.wrapper3 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-origin: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; gap: 200px">
  <div class="wrapper1 component1">
    <div class="wrapper2"></div>
    <div class="wrapper3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper1 component2">
    <div class="wrapper2"></div>
    <div class="wrapper3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I basically want `component1` and `component2` to have gradient not continuing but `component1` and `component2` must have discontinuous gradient. [Expecting similar outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUnZQ.png)

Comment: Don't tell us down here. _Improve your question._

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to do it since setting up *background:* to `linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);`, meaning from left to right it will change the color and it's 100% and you cannot cut it. The `background-attachment: fixed;` you added make share color on your `.wrapper` class, but you cannot start over on your side div.

If you really need to do it, i suggest to make it manually(*not recommended*). I just made this so you can refer to it.

```css
.wrapper{
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  gap: 200px;
}
.wrapper1 {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  left: 80px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  left: -40px;
}

.wrapper3 {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  right: 90px;
}

.wrapper1.component1,
.component1 .wrapper2,
.component1 .wrapper3{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 1px, blue 200px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-origin: content-box;
  
}

.wrapper1.component2,
.component2 .wrapper2,
.component2 .wrapper3{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 230px, blue 430px);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-origin: content-box;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper1 component1">
    <div class="wrapper2"></div>
    <div class="wrapper3"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper1 component2">
    <div class="wrapper2"></div>
    <div class="wrapper3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This could be implemented, but the catch here is in the above code snippet I have used only 2 occurrences, but I have to incorporate this to n elements using JavaScript, using which to find at what point the gradient ends would not be possible